# Is registering an international domain (CCTLD) unsafe?

Tags: domains, cctld

Since you provide personal information when registering a domain, is it more unsafe for your private information when registering an international domain (such as .cd for the Democratic Republic of the Congo) as opposed to a .com domain?

Comment: I believe you need to define your threat model a little better. You typically register domain names going through a registrar. It may or may not be bound by same laws than the registry, depending on where they are located. Add third case if you are using a reseller. Some registrar/reseller can also provide proxy/privacy service and then your own personal data will not reach the registry. Also do you care about public access like through whois or just owning your data. Note also the GDPR that still profundly change the way things work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each CCTLD is operated by a regional registry bound by local law, so this is really a question of whether a CCTLD registry is trustworthy and resides in a country with sane laws. So the answer will vary per country.

For example the `.com` TLD is run by Verisign, which is a company based in the US and bound by US law. Likewise the `.us` CCTLD is run by NeuStar, which is based in Virginia, USA and also bound by US law. The `.ch` domain name operated by SWITCH in Switzerland is an example of a CCTLD that is bound by even stricter privacy rules than the ones in the USA.

On the other side of the spectrum, there are countries with governments that most people would agree are oppressive, and their CCTLD registries are bound by their relatively less fair, less coherent legal systems. These countries may not have any privacy laws, or any legal recourse if your registration information is used nefariously. CCTLD operators are for the most part pretty trustworthy as far as I know, but I could think of a few I would stay away from just due to their country's backwards legal system.

So in essence, CCTLDs are as safe and reputable as their registries, which are bound by the laws of their respective countries. Find out the registry organization for each of the CCTLDs here:

https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

...then you can do research on them and determine whether you trust them.

Comment: `.COM` is a specific case still for now, as it is a thin registry, so contact data never reach the registry and stay at the registrar. This will change in the following months.

Comment: Also, some ccTLDs allow personal registrations only if you give basically your national identification number or equivalent. Or if you prove who you are by screenshot of some identification papers. How is this then stored and handled is anyone guess.

Comment: But please remember that icannwiki.org is not an authoritative source (it is not run by ICANN) as its name imply its content can be changed by "anybody". IANA root database at https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db is the authoritative source but you will not find there information on eligibility requirements.

Comment: Also remember that registries can change. Look at the recent case of `.SK`.